# Give every property of object value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, properties

I have an object and array, every element in array corresponds to object property.

It looks line this:

```js
let keys = {
  kShift: null,
  kSpace: null,
  kEnter: null,
  kA: null,
  kS: null,
  kD: null,
  kW: null
}

let array = document.querySelectorAll('.k')
```

```html
<div class="k">shift</div>
<div class="k">space</div>
<div class="k">enter</div>
<div class="k">a</div>
<div class="k">s</div>
<div class="k">d</div>
<div class="k">w</div>
```

I need every property of object to get corresponding value from array.

it looks so:

```
  keys.kShift = array[0] // first property of object is the first element in array
  keys.kSpace = array[1] // second property of object is the second element in array
  keys.kEnter = array[2] // third property of object is the third element in array
```

and so on

**So i need to find the best way to do it**

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 destructuring for array. Have to make sure the array items on right are in same order as the declared variables.

```
const [ kShift, kSpace, kEnter, kA, kS, kD, kW ] = document.querySelectorAll('.k')
const keys = { kShift, kSpace, kEnter, kA, kS, kD, kW }
```